# How to set godot4 game screen resolution when launched

Tags: fullscreen, screen-resolution, godot4

Because my **fullscreen** godot game would be avaliable on many platforms (e.g. mac, windows) so I have to make sure that everytime my game launches on it's first time, it checks the OS and device it's on and sets the **correct resolution** for the device. How do I do this? I want something like this:

```
func _ready():
    device = project.get_device()
    project_settings.set_setting("window_width", device.width)
    project_settings.set_setting("window_height", device.height)
    project_settings.save()
```

note that the code I wrote is not actual GDscript, it's just an example of something I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set project settings like this:

```
ProjectSettings.set("display/window/size/viewport_width", 320)
ProjectSettings.set("display/window/size/viewport_height", 240)
```

But for the time your code runs, it is too late for that. You could instead get the window and set the size, like this:

```
get_window().size = Vector2(320, 240)
```

Or the viewport:

```
get_viewport().size = Vector2(320, 240)
```

---

To identify the platforms you can use [`OS.get_name()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-name):

```
prints(OS.get_name())
```

Or work with [`OS.has_feature()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-has-feature)

---

But better yet, don't do this by code. Instead go to Project Settings and define overrides for the platforms you want.

For example, if I want to override the width for Android, I select Viewport Width:

[image: Viewport Width selected]

Then select the feature "android" from the drop down list at the top:

[image: Selecting "android"]

Then click on add:

[image: Hovering on add]

That adds a new "Viewport Width.android" property that will be effective on targets that has the feature "android" (i.e. on Android platforms):

[image: "Viewport Width.android" selected]

Which you can set to whatever you want.

Comment: so I can add different screen sizes for different platforms?